# My coding seems inefficient... Any way to speed it up?

Tags: java

So I tried this program which was supposed to find out what position these doors are in. They start out closed, and then you toggle every door. The next time you toggle every second, then every third, fourth, so on. I got the coding right but it seems really inefficient. If I tried this with larger numbers, then the program would take too long. Is there any way to do this more efficiently? Here is my coding:

```
 public class doors
 {
  public static void main(String [] args)
  {
    int x, y = 1;
    boolean [] doors = new boolean[100];
    for (int a = 0; a < doors.length; a++)
      doors[a] = false; //false means closed
    do
    {
      for (x = 0; x < doors.length - 1; x++)
      {
        if ((x+1) % y == 0)
        {
          if (doors[x] == true)
            doors[x] = false;
          else if (doors[x] == false)
            doors[x] = true;
        }        
      }
      y++;
    }while (y <= doors.length);
    for (boolean b : doors)
    System.out.println(b);
  }
}
    // Thanks!!!
```

Comment: This is better suited for codereview.stackexchange.com, and should be moved there.

Comment: Ask your question at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: One small thing is to remove the `if/else` check on the value change, and just do `doors[x] = !doors[x]`. It will remove the comparison check. However, for better review, the codereview site is a good choice.

Comment: Agree that this is off topic here, but your whole 4 line true/false flipper could be `doors[x] = !doors[x];` instead of an if.

Comment: Sorry, i am new to this and don't know exactly what to put where... Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's simplify the code one step at a time.

---

1) When an array is allocated, all elements are initialized to their default value, which means `0`, `false`, or `null`. In your case that means `false`, so no need to loop through and do that.

```
// before
boolean [] doors = new boolean[100];
for (int a = 0; a < doors.length; a++)
    doors[a] = false; //false means closed

// after
boolean[] doors = new boolean[100];
```

---

2a) Since the array is not a zero-length array, the `do-while` loop might as well be a normal `while` loop (it will execute at least once).

2b) As a normal `while` loop, with an initializer right before the loop, and the increment at the end of the loop, it is the same as a `for` loop.

2c) Since `y` is not used after the loop, it can be declared in the loop.

```
// before
int x, y = 1;
do
{
    //code
    y++;
}while (y <= doors.length);

// after
int x;
for (int y = 1; y <= doors.length; y++)
{
    //code
}
```

---

3a) `doors[x] == true` is the same as `doors[x]`. `doors[x] == false` is the same as `! doors[x]`.

3b) `if (x) {} else if (! x) {}` is the same as `if (x) {} else {}`. The test after `else` is redundant.

3c) `if (x) x = false; else x = true;` is the same as `x = ! x;`.

3d) You can skip the double evaluation by doing `^= true` (XOR).

```
// before
if (doors[x] == true)
    doors[x] = false;
else if (doors[x] == false)
    doors[x] = true;

// after
doors[x] = ! doors[x];

// skip double evaluation of index lookup
doors[x] ^= true;
```

---

4a) `(x+1) % y == 0` will only be true for `x` values of `y-1`, `2*y-1`, `3*y-1`, and so on, so make loop start at `y-1` and increment by `y`, eliminating the need for the `if` statement.

4c) Since `x` is not used after the loop, it can be declared in the loop.

```
// before
int x;
for (x = 0; x < doors.length - 1; x++)
{
    if ((x+1) % y == 0)
    {
        //code
    }
}

// after
for (int x = y - 1; x < doors.length - 1; x += y)
{
    //code
}
```

---

**Result so far** (after also removing unnecessary braces)

```
boolean[] doors = new boolean[100];
for (int y = 1; y <= doors.length; y++)
    for (int x = y - 1; x < doors.length - 1; x += y)
        doors[x] ^= true;
for (boolean b : doors)
    System.out.println(b);
```

---

5a) Limiting `x` to `< doors.length - 1` means that last value of the array will never be used/updated. Drop the `- 1`.

```
// before
for (int x = y - 1; x < doors.length - 1; x += y)

// after
for (int x = y - 1; x < doors.length; x += y)
```

---

6a) Printing the array with one boolean `true`/`false` value per lines is not very human readable. Print is as a binary number on one line.

```
// before
for (boolean b : doors)
    System.out.println(b);

// after
for (boolean b : doors)
    System.out.print(b ? '1' : '0');
System.out.println();
```

---

7a) Move the printing inside the outer loop, and you'll see an interesting pattern.

```
boolean[] doors = new boolean[100];
for (int y = 1; y <= doors.length; y++) {
    for (int x = y - 1; x < doors.length; x += y)
        doors[x] ^= true;
    for (boolean b : doors)
        System.out.print(b ? '1' : '0');
    System.out.println();
}
```

```
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
1010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010
1000111000111000111000111000111000111000111000111000111000111000111000111000111000111000111000111000
1001111100101001111100101001111100101001111100101001111100101001111100101001111100101001111100101001
1001011101101011111000100001101100001000111110101101110100111001011101101011111000100001101100001000
1001001101111011101000110001111100011000101110111101100100101001001101111011101000110001111100011000
1001000101111111101010110000111100111000111110110101100000101011001100111011001000100001110100011100
1001000001111110101010100000111000111001111110100101100100101010001100101011001100100000110100001100
1001000011111110111010100010111000101001111100100101110100101000001100111011001110100000100100001110
1001000010111110111110100010101000101000111100100001110100111000001101111011001010100000110100001111
1001000010011110111111100010101010101000111000100001111100111000011101111011101010100001110100001101
1001000010001110111111110010101010111000111000110001111100101000011101101011101010110001110100011101
1001000010000110111111110110101010111010111000110000111100101000111101101011111010110001111100011101
1001000010000010111111110111101010111010101000110000111000101000111100101011111010100001111100011001
1001000010000000111111110111111010111010101010110000111000111000111100101001111010100001101100011001
1001000010000001111111110111111110111010101010100000111000111001111100101001111110100001101100001001
1001000010000001011111110111111111111010101010100010111000111001111000101001111110101001101100001001
1001000010000001001111110111111111101010101010100010101000111001111000111001111110101001111100001001
1001000010000001000111110111111111101110101010100010101010111001111000111000111110101001111100101001
1001000010000001000011110111111111101111101010100010101010101001111000111000111010101001111100101000
1001000010000001000001110111111111101111111010100010101010101011111000111000111010111001111100101000
1001000010000001000000110111111111101111111110100010101010101011101000111000111010111000111100101000
1001000010000001000000010111111111101111111111100010101010101011101010111000111010111000111000101000
1001000010000001000000000111111111101111111111110010101010101011101010101000111010111000111000111000
1001000010000001000000001111111111101111111111110110101010101011101010101010111010111000111000111001
1001000010000001000000001011111111101111111111110111101010101011101010101010101010111000111000111001
1001000010000001000000001001111111101111111111110111111010101011101010101010101000111000111000111001
1001000010000001000000001000111111101111111111110111111110101011101010101010101000101000111000111001
1001000010000001000000001000011111101111111111110111111111101011101010101010101000101010111000111001
1001000010000001000000001000001111101111111111110111111111111011101010101010101000101010101000111001
1001000010000001000000001000000111101111111111110111111111111111101010101010101000101010101010111001
1001000010000001000000001000000011101111111111110111111111111110101010101010101000101010101010101001
1001000010000001000000001000000001101111111111110111111111111110111010101010101000101010101010101011
1001000010000001000000001000000000101111111111110111111111111110111110101010101000101010101010101011
1001000010000001000000001000000000001111111111110111111111111110111111101010101000101010101010101011
1001000010000001000000001000000000011111111111110111111111111110111111111010101000101010101010101011
1001000010000001000000001000000000010111111111110111111111111110111111111110101000101010101010101011
1001000010000001000000001000000000010011111111110111111111111110111111111111101000101010101010101011
1001000010000001000000001000000000010001111111110111111111111110111111111111111000101010101010101011
1001000010000001000000001000000000010000111111110111111111111110111111111111111100101010101010101011
1001000010000001000000001000000000010000011111110111111111111110111111111111111101101010101010101011
1001000010000001000000001000000000010000001111110111111111111110111111111111111101111010101010101011
1001000010000001000000001000000000010000000111110111111111111110111111111111111101111110101010101011
1001000010000001000000001000000000010000000011110111111111111110111111111111111101111111101010101011
1001000010000001000000001000000000010000000001110111111111111110111111111111111101111111111010101011
1001000010000001000000001000000000010000000000110111111111111110111111111111111101111111111110101011
1001000010000001000000001000000000010000000000010111111111111110111111111111111101111111111111101011
1001000010000001000000001000000000010000000000000111111111111110111111111111111101111111111111111011
1001000010000001000000001000000000010000000000001111111111111110111111111111111101111111111111111111
1001000010000001000000001000000000010000000000001011111111111110111111111111111101111111111111111110
1001000010000001000000001000000000010000000000001001111111111110111111111111111101111111111111111110
1001000010000001000000001000000000010000000000001000111111111110111111111111111101111111111111111110
1001000010000001000000001000000000010000000000001000011111111110111111111111111101111111111111111110
1001000010000001000000001000000000010000000000001000001111111110111111111111111101111111111111111110
1001000010000001000000001000000000010000000000001000000111111110111111111111111101111111111111111110
1001000010000001000000001000000000010000000000001000000011111110111111111111111101111111111111111110
1001000010000001000000001000000000010000000000001000000001111110111111111111111101111111111111111110
1001000010000001000000001000000000010000000000001000000000111110111111111111111101111111111111111110
1001000010000001000000001000000000010000000000001000000000011110111111111111111101111111111111111110
1001000010000001000000001000000000010000000000001000000000001110111111111111111101111111111111111110
1001000010000001000000001000000000010000000000001000000000000110111111111111111101111111111111111110
1001000010000001000000001000000000010000000000001000000000000010111111111111111101111111111111111110
1001000010000001000000001000000000010000000000001000000000000000111111111111111101111111111111111110
1001000010000001000000001000000000010000000000001000000000000001111111111111111101111111111111111110
1001000010000001000000001000000000010000000000001000000000000001011111111111111101111111111111111110
1001000010000001000000001000000000010000000000001000000000000001001111111111111101111111111111111110
1001000010000001000000001000000000010000000000001000000000000001000111111111111101111111111111111110
1001000010000001000000001000000000010000000000001000000000000001000011111111111101111111111111111110
1001000010000001000000001000000000010000000000001000000000000001000001111111111101111111111111111110
1001000010000001000000001000000000010000000000001000000000000001000000111111111101111111111111111110
1001000010000001000000001000000000010000000000001000000000000001000000011111111101111111111111111110
1001000010000001000000001000000000010000000000001000000000000001000000001111111101111111111111111110
1001000010000001000000001000000000010000000000001000000000000001000000000111111101111111111111111110
1001000010000001000000001000000000010000000000001000000000000001000000000011111101111111111111111110
1001000010000001000000001000000000010000000000001000000000000001000000000001111101111111111111111110
1001000010000001000000001000000000010000000000001000000000000001000000000000111101111111111111111110
1001000010000001000000001000000000010000000000001000000000000001000000000000011101111111111111111110
1001000010000001000000001000000000010000000000001000000000000001000000000000001101111111111111111110
1001000010000001000000001000000000010000000000001000000000000001000000000000000101111111111111111110
1001000010000001000000001000000000010000000000001000000000000001000000000000000001111111111111111110
1001000010000001000000001000000000010000000000001000000000000001000000000000000011111111111111111110
1001000010000001000000001000000000010000000000001000000000000001000000000000000010111111111111111110
1001000010000001000000001000000000010000000000001000000000000001000000000000000010011111111111111110
1001000010000001000000001000000000010000000000001000000000000001000000000000000010001111111111111110
1001000010000001000000001000000000010000000000001000000000000001000000000000000010000111111111111110
1001000010000001000000001000000000010000000000001000000000000001000000000000000010000011111111111110
1001000010000001000000001000000000010000000000001000000000000001000000000000000010000001111111111110
1001000010000001000000001000000000010000000000001000000000000001000000000000000010000000111111111110
1001000010000001000000001000000000010000000000001000000000000001000000000000000010000000011111111110
1001000010000001000000001000000000010000000000001000000000000001000000000000000010000000001111111110
1001000010000001000000001000000000010000000000001000000000000001000000000000000010000000000111111110
1001000010000001000000001000000000010000000000001000000000000001000000000000000010000000000011111110
1001000010000001000000001000000000010000000000001000000000000001000000000000000010000000000001111110
1001000010000001000000001000000000010000000000001000000000000001000000000000000010000000000000111110
1001000010000001000000001000000000010000000000001000000000000001000000000000000010000000000000011110
1001000010000001000000001000000000010000000000001000000000000001000000000000000010000000000000001110
1001000010000001000000001000000000010000000000001000000000000001000000000000000010000000000000000110
1001000010000001000000001000000000010000000000001000000000000001000000000000000010000000000000000010
1001000010000001000000001000000000010000000000001000000000000001000000000000000010000000000000000000
1001000010000001000000001000000000010000000000001000000000000001000000000000000010000000000000000001
```

---

Now, when you look at the pattern of the result (last line), you'll see that your code could be reduced to (**very fast**):

```
boolean[] doors = new boolean[100];
for (int idx = 0, incr = 1; idx < doors.length; idx += (incr += 2))
    doors[idx] = true;
//print here
```

```
1001000010000001000000001000000000010000000000001000000000000001000000000000000010000000000000000001
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped. Forgive me, but I am fairly new to programming. What does the ^= mean?

Comment: @SamuelBrice `^=` is a [compound assignment operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26) similar to `+=`, i.e. `a ^= b` is short for `a = a ^ b`. `^` is the exclusive OR operator, which can be used for [integer bitwise operations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.1) or [logical boolean operations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.2), which is what I'm doing here.

Answer (score 1):

First, the default value in your `doors` array is false (but you could use `Arrays.fill` to fill it if you needed to). Next you only need to increment your loop by `y`. Then you can toggle with `doors[x] = !doors[x];`. Something like,

```
int y = 1;
boolean[] doors = new boolean[100];
// Arrays.fill(doors, false);
do {
    for (int x = y - 1; x < doors.length; x += y) {
        doors[x] = !doors[x];
    }
    y++;
} while (y <= doors.length);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(doors));
```

**or** using nested `for` loops like

```
boolean[] doors = new boolean[100];
// Arrays.fill(doors, false);
for (int y = 1; y < doors.length; y++) {
    for (int x = y - 1; x <= doors.length; x += y) {
        doors[x] = !doors[x];
    }
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(doors));
```

Comment: `(x+1) % y == 0` is true for the following values of `x`: `y-1`, `2*y-1`, `3*y-1`, ..., so loop should start with `int x = y - 1`. --- Also, outer `do-while` loop can be a simple `for` loop too. Simplifies code.

Comment: Code has `y <= doors.length`. You missed the `=`.

Answer (score 0):

As the guys have mentioned above there is a bunch of things you could do to simplify the code. By doing that you will start to better see the algorithms being used and therefore see where they can be improved.

With code like this, simplifying things like if statements is usually more about clarifying code than improving performance. The reason I say that is compilers these days and very good as optimising code and whilst a few instructions may be dropped the performance difference is likely to be minimal.

Where you are more likely to gain noticeable improvement is where there are loops. Reducing the number of iterations in a loop will often have a dramatic effect on overall time. To that end I can see two possible places you can improve things.

Firstly the initial setup loop may not be required. I haven't checked, but the array of doors may be false by default, so looping through to initialise could possibly be dropped.

Secondly, the inner loop increments by 1 and tests if that door matches y. You can short circuit a lot of this by simply incrementing the inner loop by y. That way you will always be on a door you want to flip. Which means you can drop the  test for the correct door, and just flip it. As y increases, the number of iterations of the x loop would decrease. Meaning that it would speed up each time y increased.

Finally when I see code like this I always recommend one thing. Always put brackets on your if statements. Subtle bugs are easy to introduce when brackets are not used.

Answer (score -6):

instead of using for statement , use foreach and switch instead

example

```
for(boolean i:doors){
   //do something  
            }
```

Comment: How do you change the current value with foreach?